# EditText is throwing a fatal error

Tags: android, android-edittext, logcat

I had an app that was working perfectly. Once I added AdViews to it, my EditText started throwing an error. Here is the EditText from the XML Layout.

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editOriginalBalance"
```

Here is the /java line that is throwing the error:

```
        final EditText viewOriginalBalance = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editOriginalBalance);
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): Process: biz.midl.debtcalculator, PID: 1133
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{biz.midl.debtcalculator/biz.midl.debtcalculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at biz.midl.debtcalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-23 10:48:14.249: E/AndroidRuntime(1133):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

To me, this is saying that I'm taking a TextView and casting it as an EditText. The issue is -- it really is an EditText getting cast as an EditText.

I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: just clean and build your project once

Comment: Your xml layout is not being recompiled... check for errors. If you do a Project / Clean, R won't compile. I assume you had a TextView before and then you changed it to an EditText, yes? There must be some subtle error you can hardly see.

Comment: That worked - thanks Artoo Detoo!